# How can I use a Lambda/Action/Delegate in my code?

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, action

I have to demonstrate a use of Lambdas/Actions/Delegates within my program for my A-Level to make it more complex.
I know how to make them all and (kind of) what they do, but not when to use them.

Can anybody let me know where in my code I can use one, two or all of these? I wasn't sure if this was the right place for this, let me know if not.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

//Command-Line Arguements for SizeX and SizeY

namespace prjT02L08_Predator_Prey
{
    public partial class frmSim : Form
    {
        Point GridSize; //Creates a pair of X and Y co-ordinates
        Random r = new Random(); //Used for any random number needed in the program
        float FoodSpawnChance = 50; //The chance that food has of spawning
        int SimTick = 0; //How long the program has been running for
        int ImageScale = 7; //How much to scale the bitmap grid up for displaying
        int SizeX = 60; //The number of pixels on the X axis
        int SizeY = 60; //The number of pixels on the Y axis

    bool StepDone = true; //Has one update of the simulation happened?

    public frmSim() //Main constructor method
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GridSize = new Point(SizeX, SizeY); //Sets the size of the grid using the size of the X and Y axis
        AStar.Grid = Node.MakeGrid(GridSize.X, GridSize.Y, 10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            new Mitosis(r.Next(0, SizeX) /*Produces a random number between 0 and the size of the X axis*/,
                r.Next(0, SizeY)/*Random number between 0 and the size of the Y axis*/); //Adds new Mitosis bacteria for the first time

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            new Meiosis(r.Next(0, SizeX), r.Next(0, SizeY)); //Adds new Meiosis bacteria for the first time
        chkNaturalSpawn.Checked = true; //Sets the food's natural spawn to true, so it randomly spawns
    }

    private void UpdateSim() //Updates the whole simulation
    {
        UpdateVars(); //Updates all the variables in the simulation

        if (SimTick == 20) //If the simulation has run for 20 ticks,
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                new VirusP(1, 1); //Creates a new virus at the X position 1, and Y position 1

        if (chkNaturalSpawn.Checked == true) //If natural spawning has been selected
            SpawnFood(); //then try to spawn food

        Entity.UpdateAll(SimTick); //Updates all entities
    }

    private void UpdateVars() //Updates all the variables in the simulation
    {
        SimTick++; //Each timer tick, this variable is incremented
        tmrSimClock.Interval = trcInterval.Value; //The gap between ticks is set based of the trackbar (Which has been reversed right-to-left)

        if (chkNaturalSpawn.Checked == true) //Checks if natural food spawning is enabled
            FoodSpawnChance = trcFoodSpawn.Value; //then if true, sets the chance of food spawning to the value of the trackbar

        VirusP.DoubleStepChance = trcPred2Step.Value; //The chance of the Virus moving two places instead of one is set of the trackbar
    }

    private void SpawnFood() //Attempts to spawn food at a random location
    {
        //Chance to spawn based on FoodSpawnChance variable
        if (r.Next(0, 1000) < (FoodSpawnChance * 100)) //Uses a random number to determine whether food can spawn or not
        {
            int x = r.Next(0, GridSize.X); //Sets the value of x to a random number between 0 and the value of the Gridsize.X
            int y = r.Next(0, GridSize.Y); //Sets the value of y to a random number between 0 and the value of the Gridsize.Y

            if (!AStar.Grid[x, y].IsWall) //Checks if the random position chosen isn't a wall
                new Food(x, y); //then if true, food is spawned at that position

        }
    }

    private void frmSim_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnStep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (StepDone == true) //Checks if the previous update from this button has already been completed or not - Prevents slow down
        {
            StepDone = false;
            UpdateSim(); //Updates the simulation once
            DrawSim(); //Redraws the bitmap image to show a visual update
            StepDone = true;
        }
    }

    private void DrawSim() //Creates the bitmap of the grid which is dispalyed on the screen and scales it up
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(GridSize.X, GridSize.Y); //Creates the bitmap specifying the width and height of it
        //These two for loops loop through every part of the grid:
        for (int x = 0; x < GridSize.X; x++) //For every value in the height of the grid
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < GridSize.Y; y++)//and every value in the width of the grid
            {
                Color Colour = Color.Black; //Creates a new color used to set the pixel colour on the bitmap (Empty space is black)

                foreach (Entity e in Entity.GetEntitiesAt(x, y)) //For every entity a the current location...
                {
                    if ((e as Food) != null) //If it is Food, set the colour to green
                        Colour = Color.FromArgb(Colour.R, 255, Colour.B);
                    else if ((e as Mitosis) != null) //If it is bacteria Mitosis, set the colour to blue
                        Colour = Color.FromArgb(Colour.R, Colour.G, 255);
                    else if ((e as Meiosis) != null) //If it is bacteria Meiosis, set the colour to gold
                        Colour = Color.Gold;
                    else //If it's none of these, the only entity left is the Virus, set the colour to red
                        Colour = Color.FromArgb(255, Colour.G, Colour.B);
                }

                if (AStar.Grid[x, y].IsWall) //If that location is a wall, set the colour to white
                    Colour = Color.White;

                bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Colour); //Set the pixel at position x and y to the colour chosen above
            }
        }

        //Scales up the bitmap into a new bitmap
        Bitmap bmpscale = new Bitmap(GridSize.X * ImageScale, GridSize.Y * ImageScale);
        for (int x = 0; x < GridSize.X; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < GridSize.Y; y++)
            {
                for (int sx = 0; sx < ImageScale; sx++)
                {
                    for (int sy = 0; sy < ImageScale; sy++)
                    {
                        bmpscale.SetPixel(((x * ImageScale) + sx), ((y * ImageScale) + sy), bmp.GetPixel(x, y));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        this.CreateGraphics().DrawImage(bmpscale, new Point(10, 10)); //Draws the bitmap image at set co-ordinates on the form
    }

    private void tmrSimClock_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) //Every time the timer updates
    {
        UpdateSim(); //Updates the simulation
        DrawSim(); //Redraws the simulation
    }

    private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmrSimClock.Enabled = !tmrSimClock.Enabled; //Put timer in opposite state
        btnStep.Enabled = !btnStep.Enabled; //Put button in opposite state

        if (tmrSimClock.Enabled)
            btnRun.Text = "Running...";
        else
            btnRun.Text = "Run";
    }

    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Entity.Entities = new List<Entity>(); //Recreates the list of entitites
        SimTick = 0; //Restarts the simulation timer
        tmrSimClock.Enabled = false; //Turns the timer off
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)//Recreates entities Mitosis and Meiosis
        {
            new Mitosis(r.Next(0, SizeX), r.Next(0, SizeY));
            new Meiosis(r.Next(0, SizeX), r.Next(0, SizeY));
        }
        btnRun.Text = "Run";
    }

    private void chkNaturalSpawn_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblFood.Enabled = chkNaturalSpawn.Checked == true ? true : false; //Turnery Statement
        trcFoodSpawn.Enabled = chkNaturalSpawn.Checked == true ? true : false; //If checked is true, return true, else return false
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use lambda expressions to make your code more *complex* - you should use them to make your code *simpler*. Your `chkNaturalSpwan_CheckedChanged` would be simpler without the conditional expressions, too.

Comment: You could try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JonSkeet :D okay, simpler! I meant complex in the difficulty/complex for making me seem more knowledgable. Anywhere you can see?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Isn't that for reviewing code for errors or improvements, not additional code?

Comment: You can simplfy your code by writing a traverseGrid method that takes a function as a parameter and does the for (int y = 0; y < GridSize.Y; y++) { for (int sx = 0; sx < ImageScale; sx++) { function; } } stuff. Then us a lamda to do all the work in your duplicated loops in the drawsim method

Comment: @ShivamMalhotra: I would personally concentrate on making your code cleaner in any way you can (e.g. giving variables camelCased names and methods PascalCased names) rather than looking to add more "clever" language features to your code.

Comment: @Kell If you don't mind, could you go into some more detail. I'm not sure how to do what you said!

Comment: @JonSkeet Will do that now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I've got to agree with Jon: make it tidy first. This is an example of lambda use by using an action as an anonymous delegate/lambda function. You may have to fiddle to get it to work

```
private void traverseBmp(Action<int, int> doIt)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < GridSize.X; x++) //For every value in the height of the grid
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < GridSize.Y; y++)//and every value in the width of the grid
            {
                doIt(x, y);
            }
        }

    private void DrawSim() //Creates the bitmap of the grid which is dispalyed on the screen and scales it up
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(GridSize.X, GridSize.Y); //Creates the bitmap specifying the width and height of it
        //These two for loops loop through every part of the grid:
        traverseBmp((x, y) =>
            {
                Color Colour = Color.Black;
                    //Creates a new color used to set the pixel colour on the bitmap (Empty space is black)

                foreach (Entity e in Entity.GetEntitiesAt(x, y)) //For every entity a the current location...
                {
                    if ((e as Food) != null) //If it is Food, set the colour to green
                        Colour = Color.FromArgb(Colour.R, 255, Colour.B);
                    else if ((e as Mitosis) != null) //If it is bacteria Mitosis, set the colour to blue
                        Colour = Color.FromArgb(Colour.R, Colour.G, 255);
                    else if ((e as Meiosis) != null) //If it is bacteria Meiosis, set the colour to gold
                        Colour = Color.Gold;
                    else //If it's none of these, the only entity left is the Virus, set the colour to red
                        Colour = Color.FromArgb(255, Colour.G, Colour.B);
                }

                if (AStar.Grid[x, y].IsWall) //If that location is a wall, set the colour to white
                    Colour = Color.White;

                bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Colour); //Set the pixel at position x and y to the colour chosen above
            });

        //Scales up the bitmap into a new bitmap
        Bitmap bmpscale = new Bitmap(GridSize.X * ImageScale, GridSize.Y * ImageScale);
        traverseBmp((x,y) =>
            {
                for (int sx = 0; sx < ImageScale; sx++)
                {
                    for (int sy = 0; sy < ImageScale; sy++)
                    {
                        bmpscale.SetPixel(((x*ImageScale) + sx), ((y*ImageScale) + sy), bmp.GetPixel(x, y));
                    }
                }
            });

        this.CreateGraphics().DrawImage(bmpscale, new Point(10, 10)); //Draws the bitmap image at set co-ordinates on the form
    }
```